# Which website can I learn Yii framework?

Tags: yii

The official website contains so simple tutorials. Are there some good websites like ASP.NET MVC 3 from Microsoft that provide everything from scratch about Yii.

Answer (score 2):

do you checkout the [guide?](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/). it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Personal this is a great set of tutorials to learn Yii from.

http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide as mentioned, then check out the [Blog Tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/)

Answer (score 0):

i learned it on the blog tutorial, took me about half an hour to learn that way. I also suggest making a real life app with it, then you learn a lot more, since you look for ways to solve the problem that come, and questioning is the best way to learn without a doubt